# let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. show that the set $\{x \in [a,b] | f(x) = 0 \}$ is finite when a condition is met.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.  show that the set $A = \{x \in [a,b] | f(x) = 0 \}$ is finite when the set $B =\{x \in [a,b] | f(x) = f'(x) = 0 \} = \emptyset$ .

My attempt: for the sake of contradiction, suppose $A$ is infinite. then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ . then $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and so there exists a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k} \} \subset \{x_n\}$ that converges to some point $c \in [a,b]$
we also can conclude that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = f(c) = 0$.

on the other hand, by mean value theorem on every interval $[x_{n_k} , x_{n_{k+1}} ]$ there exists a point $c_k \in [x_{n_k} , x_{n_{k+1}} ]$ such that $f'(c_k) = 0$.

Now I get stuck and can't go further to reach a contradiction.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think $\{c_k\}$ must converge to c either. probably I can show that. But does that help ?  if $f'$ was continuous then the problem would be solved but  I think $f'$ is not necessarily continiuous.

Comment: I just discovered that the question has been asked before, and the identical answer has been given before. Can you please unaccept my answer so that I can delete it? Thanks.